# Give background to alternate <DIV> rows

Tags: html, css

I have a `<DIV>` structure table, I want to give background color for alternate rows.

Initially my `<DIV>` structure was this **(as show in [Fiddle - **Option 1*](http://jsfiddle.net/EX856/)**):*

**HTML**

```
<div class="Case">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .Case {
    border:1px solid #dbdbde;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.group {
    display:table;
    border-top: 1px solid #dbdbde;
    width: 100%;
}
.group div {
    vertical-align:top;
}
.group:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
.subdiv {
    display:table-cell;
    border-left:1px solid #dbdbde;
    padding:10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.subdiv:nth-child(1) {
    border-left:none;
}
```

It was working Fine!!! **BUT when I added one more Row of "Empty" DIV** this "`.group:nth-child(even) {background-color:#f9f9f9;}`" code stopped working.

**(as show in [Fiddle - **Option 2*](http://jsfiddle.net/EX856/)**):*

Here is the NEW code:
**HTML**

```
<div class="Case">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
     <div class="empty"></div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
     <div class="empty"></div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
     <div class="empty"></div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
     <div class="empty"></div>
</div>
```

CSS is same just added as top juist added style for the ".empty" class

```
   .empty {
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:15px;
}
```

Please suggest what am I missing???

Comment: There is no code in your fiddles and coloring does work for both.

Comment: Not answering your question - but wondering why you're re-creating a table using `<div>`s, why not use `<table>`

Comment: I can see my code... and coloring workks for Option one... but not for Option 2

Comment: @NickR: becouse this is all auto generating... I am just giving styles to a auto generated DIVs to look like table

Comment: It doesn't work in option 2 because adding `<div class="empty"></div>` breaks your `nth` child selector flow, so you need to skip the empty divs.

Comment: @AT-UID "It's auto generated" isn't a very good reason to have bad markup.  If you're unable to modify it, there's not a lot that can be done.  If you *can* adjust it (and it sounds like you can), you absolutely should.  This looks like tabular data and it should belong in a table.  Also, empty elements are a pretty terrible kludge and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that nth child counts **all** the elements, not just the elements of the class that you set in the selector.

One posible solution is not to create a separator div.

Instead, set an aditional class in your container, and then make the divs be more spaced thru a margin-bottom (and a shadow to make the space gray).

HTML (fragment)

```
<h1>Option 2</h1>

<div class="Case sep">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
        <div class="Time subdiv"></div>
        <div class="Committer subdiv">gdfg</div>
        <div class="Description subdiv">dfgdfg</div>
        <div class="ChangeSetFiles subdiv">gdfgfgdg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="Link subdiv">ghdfgdfg</div>
```

I have deleted the empty rows, and added the sep class to the container.

In the CSS, add

```
.sep .group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px #ccc;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EX856/7/)

Answer (score 2):

It will break the first format but you can try

```
.group:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Z3eE/)

Comment: Thanks for looking into!!! But this is not working for me!! just to clarify more.. there cane be N no of ".group"s.. 10..20..30... they are generating at run time!!

Comment: @AT-UID the fiddle seems to be working... can you try to recreate the problem in the fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't understand your question very much so let try this:

```
<div class="group empty"></div>
```